# fwrite doens't save full array in C

Tags: c++, c, fwrite, fread

I have an array of size 668x493 which i want to save. So i am doing the following.

data : is a pointer to an array that holds the values.

```
long lSize;
FILE* image_save;
image_save=fopen("image_save_file.bin","w+b");
fwrite(data,1,329324,image_save);
```

However, when i read back this array:

```
char* check_image;

p1File=fopen("image_save_file.bin","r+b");

fseek (p1File , 0 , SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell (p1File);
fseek (p1File , 0 , SEEK_SET);
```

when i check lSize, i see it 327680 ???

So of course when i do fread i get only 327680 values !

Kindly asking, can you pinpoint my mistake ?

Comment: What's the return value from fwrite - does it report 329324 or 327680 elements saved?

Comment: Check the return value of your fwrite for an error, as well as the fseek.  Also, did you close the file first before re-opening?  (Incomplete source fragments make it hard to tell)

Comment: I hope it is an array of char you are saving. Anything bigger and you are not saving enough data. As mentioned before. Post a piece of code we can **compile** otherwise your answer will be partial guess work. Which wastes our time any yours.

Answer (score 10):

Interestingly, 327680 is an exact multiple of 4096 (80 * 4096).

Are you flushing/closing the output file before you read the data back in?

Comment: @Tomalak - thanks. The discrepancy noted appeared consistent with a lack of flush on write data, so checking whether read data size was a multiple of a very common disk sector and OS buffer size seemed logical.

Comment: Thank you very much :) i forgot to close the file after saving it :).. Now it works.

Comment: Why is the multiple part important? Just an interesting observation, or does it mean something?

Answer (score 5):

The `fwrite()` function is buffered. Try flushing the data on the file stream and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much :) i forgot to close the file after saving it :).. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

fwrite returns an int indicating the actual number of bytes written. Double check to make sure this differs from expected (it almost certainly does). Then, you can use [perror](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/perror/) to print out the error that's occurring.